# Polymorphism and data hiding: Does a base class override or ignore a derived class' access restrictions?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Please look at the following code listing:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual void Message() = 0;
};

class Intermediate : public Base {

};

class Final : public Intermediate {
    void Message() {
        cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Final final;
    /* Wont work (obviously):
    Final* finalPtr = &final;
    finalPtr->Message();
    */
    // Works:
    Intermediate* finalPtr = &final; // or Base* finalPtr = &final;
    finalPtr->Message();

    return 0;
}
```

Take note of the following:

1. In the abstract **Base** class, the pure virtual function **message()** is public
2. **Intermediate** class (also abstract) inherits from **Base** class (Does **message()** function remain public pure virtual in **Intermediate**?)
3. **Final** class inherits from **Intermediate** class and **message() function is private** (by default)
4. In main, an object of type **Final** is created
5. An **Intermediate** pointer to the **Final** object is created

**Question:**
If you run the program, the line **finalPtr->Message();** successfully invokes **Final**'s implementation of **message()** function though its **private**. How does that happen? Does a base class override or ignore a derived class' access restrictions?

**Related Question:**
In relation to (2.) above, what is the right way to define **Intermediate** class? Does one need to re-declare the pure virtual function **message()** from the base class bearing in mind that **Intermediate** class is not intended to provide an implementation.

**NOTE:** Code was tested with both Digital Mars Compiler (dmc) and Microsoft's Visual Studio Compiler (cl) and works just fine in both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does that happen? Does a base class override or ignore a derived class' access restrictions?

With Public Inheritance all public members of the Base class become public members of the derived class. So Yes `Message()` is public function in `Intermediate`.

The function is called on a base class(`Intermediate`) pointer the function is public in base class. The dynamic dispatch(i.e the actual call to Derived class function) only happens at runtime hence this works.

The above is due to the fact that at runtime, the access specifiers have no meaning, the access specifier rules are resolved and effective only at compile time.

If you call the function on the derived class pointer then at compile time the compiler detects that `Message()` is declared `private` in `Final` and hence it gives the error.

---

While deriving from an Abstract class, the derived class **MUST** provide definition for **ALL** the Pure virtual functions of the Base class, Failing to do so will result in the Derived class also being an Abstract class.

Here `Intermediate` class is an Abstract class and as long as you do not need to create objects of this class, it will work fine. Note that you can create a pointer to an Abstract class.

Comment: Thanks @Als. I just have a comment about: "With Public Inheritance all public members of the Base class become public members of the derived class."If you look at the commented code, a pointer of type **Final** wont invoke the **message()** function. Meaning that the **Final** class considers that method private, but its base class doesn't. That is part of the mystery.

Comment: @JohnGathogo: Updated to answer your query.

Comment: "The dynamic dispatch(i.e the actual call to Derived class function) only happens at runtime hence this works" - this would explain why it works

Comment: "you can create a pointer to an Abstract class." I would hope so, otherwise `virtual` functions would have much less usefulness. :P This is the basis of the 'interface' pattern. I'm doing a lot now with abstract/pure virtual bases that get inherited by heterogeneous templated types, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, virtual and access specifiers are mutually exclusive. That is the reason why in C++, the access can be narrowed for virtual methods whereas in C# or Java that is not possible.

When you try to access the virtual function through base class pointer, the compiler compiles the code since the base class' virtual function is public.

In your commented code, the virtual function having restricted access is called via the Final class pointer. Hence the compilation error.